# Using CodePlex Feature Generator

Tags: 2007, feature-activation, content-type

I was just wonder whether any acutally used the feature generator from codeplex or not. I have following questions...

1. Does it create good version (meaning not missing anything major from feature) for the content type?
2. Now I need to move the feature that I generated using the tool. But this feature has guids that are pertaining to my local dev box.
3. How do I go by changing those site columns (text, date , lookup columns guids) guids in Test or Production server?

I heard there are 4 activation type events with feature deployment. Can anyone help me find out how i go by changing the dev box site columns guid to the target machine site columns guids. May be there are some good blog on this. I lacked to find the right/correct one that fits my need. or May be I am lacking the keywords that would satisfy my requirements. I hope this makes sense. I am really looking for specific answers or some good links.

Comment: For editorial information, External content types are a feature specific to SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a common issue and the resolution comes down to development practices.

What I've done in the past is that any columns that are used by my feature are generated within the solution, therefore I am explicitly defining the GUIDs for the site columns and I can preserve these throughout whatever environment the solution is deployed on.

If a feature absolutely must use already existing site columns within an environment, then I'd use some other method of identifying those columns, for instance using the InternalName.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Greatly appreciate. Now I know I was thinking like pros like you. Again, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

http://spwcmfeaturegen.codeplex.com/

Comment: vivek, good codeplex stuff. I will look into this and how helpful this going to be. I need content types feature where on feature activation it will get about 30 site columns from the site collection and add them to the CT. The content type then will be delivered to different customers and all they will do is to deploy. (and they will deploy the site columns feature b4 this).

Comment: 1. I have lists on the site collection levl
2. Need site columns feature on the site collection level and there are some lookup site columns that are using the lists. thats why step 1 is creating about 9 lists. on site activation i also need to need to look for those lists and make sure lookup columns have the correct values for the list guid.
3. content type is basically similar theory like step 2.

Hope I am making sense.